# How to usevalueChange() and snapshotChanges() method to get the data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, httpclient, angularfire2

I'm working on an Angular Firebase Project, where I need data form `firestore collection`. Currently I'm using `valueChanges()` method in my service code (inside getUser methods, as shown below) to get the data . But it gives me key value as `undefined`, when I try to get key value inside my template file. I tried to go with `snapshotChanges()` method, but can't work around how to use it to get key values along with getting the data . Below are my Angular `FirebaseService, employee.component.ts , user.service.ts  and employee.component.html` (template file) Code respectively:

employee.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  public user = [];
  constructor(
    private userservice:UserService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  title = "Employees";
  ngOnInit( ) {
    this.userservice.getUser();
  }

}
```

user.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection,AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  readonly userspath = "Development/users/users";
  collectionRef= "Development"
  usersRef="users"

  public usersArray = [];

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { }

getUser({
this.afs.collection(this.collectionRef).doc(this.usersRef).collection(this.usersRef).valueChanges()
 .subscribe(res => (this.usersArray = res));
 }
```

}

employee.component.html file

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
          <th>Employee</th>
          <th>Designation</th>
          <th>Branch</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>##</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
          <tr *ngFor="let user of userArry">
              <td>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <img src="assets/images/employee/indian-office-worker-.jpg" class="emp-img">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                          {{user.Fuulname}}
                      </div>   
                  </div> 
              </td>
              <td>{{user.designation}}</td>
              <td>{{user.branch}}</td>
              <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">View Profile</button></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: what do you mean with `key value`? I see no use of `key` anywhere in your code? Also I see nowhere that you are assigning any data to `userArry`. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
getUser(): Observable<any[]> {
  this.afs.collection(this.usersRef).snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
     this.usersArray = res
  })
}
```